# Running socket.EndReceive(ar)/BeginReceive in different thread in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sockets

I am writing a server/client socket app in C# on Windows 10 platform.
The server side code and GUI code are running in the same process. On the server side I am trying to optimize my code  as I can have 255 socket client connections. I have followed Microsoft “Synchronous Server Socket Example”. I have moved (from their example) all the logic of
“public static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)” to:

```
Task.Run(() =>
{
ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar);
});
```

.. , hoping that “ReadCallback” will be called from a different thread, therefore releasing call-back socket thread ASAP.
Is that going to create a problem since I have now call ‘socket.EndReceive(ar)’ and ‘socket.BeginReceive(…)’  called possibly from different thread?
The code is still working but I don’t know whether it is by accident or by my design. Please comment on that.

Comment: `IAsyncResult` comes from APM, `Task.Run` is TPL, you shouldn't mix the two approaches. `Task.Run` will run on the thread pool, `ReadCallback` will probably run on different thread pool thread

Comment: No, End/BeginReceive() was always called from a threadpool thread before Task/async was added.  Using Task.Run does completely defeat the point of using BeginReceive(), which was to only use a thread and run code when there's something useful to do.  Mixing is not a good idea.

Comment: Thanks Gents for the reply. So the general rule is to use APM thread pool and live TPL alone. Do I understand that correct?

Answer (score 0):

According to .Net documentation all Socket calls are threadsafe.

> **Thread Safety**
>
> Instances of this class are thread safe.

I have written other code with Begin.. and End.. in different threads.  However in hindsight it wasn't the best way to do it.

I would suggest a Task per TcpClient connection, handling the in and the out, if you really don't need and synchronization between the In and Out then that Task could spawn a In Task and an Out Task but still be under the control of the TcpClient Task.

For high performance IO, I would suggest checking out [System.IO.Pipelines](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/system-io-pipelines-high-performance-io-in-net/)

Comment: Rowan I think I will go with suggestions above. Thanks for the answer. I will certainly look at the Pipelines package.